# Firebase firestore undefined is not a function in the node modules

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to read a document from my firebase database like this:

```js
const getGameData = async () => {
  const docRef = doc(db, "games", gamePin);

  try {
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
      return docSnap.data();
    } else {
      console.log("No such document!");
      return null;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error getting document:", error);
  }
};
```

I always get this error in the

> node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.rn.js file line 1046

[image: Error information]

I have tried changing my firebase config, but what is strange is that i can write data to the database like so:

```js
const createGame = async () => {
  const pin = await getNewPin();
  const gameRef = doc(db, "games", pin.toString());
  const players = [];
  players.push({ userId, name });
  await setDoc(gameRef, {
    pin,
    gameType,
    streamingServices,
    creator: userId,
    players: players,
    gameState,
  });
  setGamePin(pin);
};
```

with no errors.

I have added logs after each firebase method, and it seems as though it never gets past the doc method, as no logs show up in my terminal. It never gets past this line: `const docRef = doc(db, "games", gamePin);`

I have also tried to change firebase version from 10.7.2 all the way down to 10.5.2 without any success.

Comment: Is the docRef correct? Can you print it and see if you have a real ref there?

Answer (score 1):

From the error message is seems that `gamePin` doesn't have a value and is `undefined`. You'll want to find where you call `getGameData` and check the value you're passing for `gamePin` there.